# Special characters in JSON

Tags: json, special-characters

I'm receiving some JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "customer": {
      "@username": "peter"
    }
  }
}
```

I then want to show the username on a page, doing this:

```
$("#result").html(data.result.customer.@username);
```

This, however, doesn't work, as `@` is an invalid character. Is there any way to go around this without changing the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.result.customer["@username"]` should provide the result you want.